# log in form submit using python

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

i have this website that i need to login through python script and it should not open a browser. i have tried using requests (a lot of examples on this site) but it doesn't work and give html of the login page itself. also is there a way to simulate ck

```
    <head></head>
<body class="page_bg">

<h1 align='center'>Machine 1</h1>
        <form action='welcome.php' method='POST'>
            <table align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><h2 align="center">Login</h2></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Username</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Password</b></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pwd1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="login" value="login"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the code i have tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_data = {
    'uname': 'admin',
    'pwd1': '<mypassword>',
    'op': 'Login'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://projectdivesy.000webhostapp.com/'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data)
print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the request to `welcome.php` page

```
url = 'https://projectdivesy.000webhostapp.com/welcome.php'
r = s.post(url, data=login_data)
```